# Android Profile Image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have made an `Activity` in which user picks the image from gallery and set this image in circular `ImageView`,
here is my part of code:

```
public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);      //camera intent
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);


}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
try {
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        cursor.close();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        //  imgView = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivprofileimg);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        new saveprofileimage().execute(custid, encodedImage);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

}


class saveprofileimage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pdilog = new ProgressDialog(MyProfile.this);
    //     pdilog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
    pdilog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        response = SaveProfileImage.getJSONfromURL(params[0] + " ", params[1]);
        JSONObject _jobject = new JSONObject(response);
        serverresult = _jobject.getString("Result");
        profileimagee = _jobject.getString("ProfileImage");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    pdilog.dismiss();
    if (serverresult.equals("Success")) {
        Picasso.with(MyProfile.this)
                .load(profileimagee)
                .into(imgView);
        new customerprofiledetails().execute(custid);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MyProfile.this, "Image couldn't be saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    super.onPostExecute(result);

}
}
```

The problem is that when the image is already there in the `ImageView` and after that I try to update the image, the image does not get updated but when the user closes and reopens the app, the updated image is there in the `ImageView`,
I want is whenever I tap on the `ImageView` and chooses an image it gets updated on the spot in just few seconds,there should not be any need to open the app again, Suggest me asap

Comment: clear cache of picasso and than try it again

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 public class PicassoTools {

    public static void clearCache (Picasso p) {
        p.cache.clear();
    }
}
```

call it using:

```
PicassoTools.clearCache(Picasso.with(context));
```

you can also try:

```
 Picasso.with(MyProfile.this)
        .load(profileimagee)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .into(imgView);
```

it will automatically refresh the file..

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the local cache residing in android memory. Try clearing up the cache.

Answer (score 2):

clear cache of picasso. If you do not clear cache memory, it loads the image from cache memory.  or
try this code:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("image_url")
.thumbnail(0.5f)
.crossFade()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return false;
    }
})

.into(profileImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `onPostExecute` just modify it like below

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pdilog.dismiss();
        if (serverresult.equals("Success")) {
            Picasso.with(MyProfile.this)
                    .load(profileimagee)
                    .into(imgView);
       finish();
       startActivity(getApplicationContext(),YourActivityName.class);
       }
```